# problem in initating pic uart

Tags: pic, uart

This is the first question in stack exchange.Ok, Im trying to initiate UART of pic microcontroller(PIC24F family). I studied uart related registers in the datasheet and wrote the code to transmit a character 'K', after compile the code, hyperterminal doesn't show anything.

Here is my header file code:

```
void init_uart1()
{
 //initiate uart1
 RPOR4bits.RP8R = 3;   //pin8
 U1MODEbits.STSEL=0;
 U1MODEbits.PDSEL=0;
 U1BRG = 25;
 U1MODEbits.UARTEN=1;
 U1STAbits.UTXEN =1;
```

}

Here is my main file:

```
    TRISB=0x0000;  //0000 0000 0000 0000
    PORTBbits.RB8=0; //set outout PORTB 8th pin 

   init_uart1();
   while (1)
    { 
       while(U1STAbits.UTXBF == 1);
       U1TXREG='K';
    }
```

whats wrong in my code?

Thxns...

Comment: what is your exact pic part number?

Comment: Pic24fj128ga202

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microchip provides peripheral library functions which you can use directly in your program instead of putting values in registers. Go to `c\Program Files\Microchip\(your compiler)\docs` you will find many documentation for it or try searching for `PIC18/PIC24/PIC32 peripheral library`. I have not worked in PIC24 but the functions are same for all the MCU series like `PIC18` `PIC24` `PIC32`. For example, for UART:

```
OpenUART(): to initialize UART channel.
putsUART(): to send string to your UART
getsUART(): to receive string from UART
```

you can use these functions directly and save your time.!

Answer (score 1):

You have RPOR4bits.RP8R = 3;   listed as pin8

In either the DIP packadge or the QFN RP8 is not pin 8.

DIP RP8 -> pin 17

QFN RP8 -> pin 14